connect to xRDP via SSH
I have a headless Ubuntu 24.04 LTS system (my server) that I configured following this guide to accept SSH connections from other computers on my local network. I also added two factor authentication to my server using Google Authenticator. I can SSH into my server from my laptop (running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) no problem, but only if I connect from the terminal. If I try to ssh into my server using Remmina, the Remmina app crashes. I suspect this is due to the server's two factor authentication. On its own, this isn't an issue, but the issue comes when I try to make RDP connections.
On my server, I also have xRDP which I can connect to via the default port 3389 using Remmina on my laptop. I'd like to bind this RDP connection to SSH for added security, but if I do this in Remmina (using RDP with SSH tunneling) the app crashes when I try to connect. Again, I suspect this is due to the server's two factor authentication on SSH connections.
So, my question is, is there a way I can connect to xRDP on my server using SSH? Ideally, I'd like an alternative to Remmina so I can connect with (almost) a single click, but a working command-line solution would be great too.

One alternative is to setup the ssh tunnel using the terminal. Once the tunnel is running, use Remmina for xrdp (use 127.0.0.1 as the IP address). If this works for you, you can write a bash script to do both.

Alternatively ask Remmina developers to add support for 2 step verification.

You may get rid of the Google authentication OTP and enable authentication keys plus password or passphrase.

I found a workaround similar to @user68186's first suggestion using ssh port forwarding. From the terminal, use something like ssh -L 3390:localhost:3389 user@server.local, enter TFA OTP, and then in Remmina use RDP with server localhost:3390. Not a perfect solution, but it works.
